# Size of malloc'd chunk seems wrong

Tags: c, malloc

I read that the 0x10 bytes preceding the address returned by malloc contains the size of the chunk of memory asked to malloc + 0x10 + 1
However, in the following piece of code, where I ask for 8bytes from malloc, the size of malloc + 0x10 + 1, should be 8+16+1=25 :

```
int main( ){
  void *p=malloc(8);
```

If I then examine the memory of the 0x10  bytes preceding the address returned by malloc:

```
(gdb) p/x p
$3 = 0x555555756260
(gdb) x/16xb 0x555555756260 - 0x10
0x555555756250: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x555555756258: 0x21    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

the size that appears is 0x21 (33). Why is it 33 and not 25?

Thanks

Comment: *"I read that ..."* - where? That isn't guaranteed by the standard *at all*. It is entirely implementation dependent. The best (only valid) reference to understand your implementation details like this is your implementation's standard library source itself.

Comment: The minimum allocatable object on your platform is probably 16, Try with *different sizes* and if it works with multiples of 16, then you're right and I am right.

Comment: I read it in a tutorial (https://blog.holbertonschool.com/hack-the-virtual-memory-malloc-the-heap-the-program-break/). So the size of a chunk return by malloc isn't predictable in a standard way?

Comment: to Antti Haapala: Yes, thanks, I checked and it works as you say with multiples of 16.

Comment: @korppu73: It should return a chunk *at least* as big as you need, but it may be larger to conform to alignment or other requirements.

Comment: when you use `malloc`, you get back a chunk _at least_ the size you requested, or `NULL`. Underneath, your chunk could very well be bigger than what you requested, depends on the implementation. But this is not something you can rely on. It's undefined behavior to access outside the bounds of your chunk.

Comment: The page you refer to discusses a **specific** C implementation. On [this page](https://blog.holbertonschool.com/category/hack-the-virtual-memory/), they tell you it is Ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64 with GCC Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3, and it says, in bold, “**Everything we cover will be true for this system/environment, but may be different on another system**.” Are you using the same system and software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [page you refer to in a comment](https://blog.holbertonschool.com/hack-the-virtual-memory-malloc-the-heap-the-program-break/) discusses a **specific** C implementation. On [this page](https://blog.holbertonschool.com/category/hack-the-virtual-memory/), they tell you it is Ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64 with GCC Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3, and it says, in bold, “**Everything we cover will be true for this system/environment, but may be different on another system**.”

C implementations are only required to produce the results specified in the C standard. The underlying mechanisms by which `malloc` and other aspects of the language work may be implemented in many different ways, and there is no reason to expect the C implementation you are using behaves in the same way as another implementation in regard to how `malloc` works internally.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. Is the structure of the malloc meta information preceding the address returned by malloc, completely implementation dependent, then?

Comment: @korppu73: Yes.